# Bug or Feature? jQuery + Chrome reporting different font-size based on zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I dropped this code into Chrome.

```
setInterval( function() { 
  console.log( $('#element').css('font-size') ); 
}, 500 );
```

If I zoomed in and out using ctrl+mousewheel it would randomly change font size to things like:

- 12.222222328186035px
- 11.818181991577148px
- 24px

The correct one is 12px. If I run this in FF, it appears the zooming is blocking so that the interval only spits 12px ever. This seems like a bug I should report to Chrome but was wondering if there's some spec I'm unaware of.

Comment: You get `24px` when the font size is below `6px`. This seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happens in safari as well, seems to be a webkit bug. The implementation of the zoom shouldn't leak to `.getComputedStyle` this way.

It is already reported [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91091)